# RIPE IPv4 Block with google cloud computing engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, ipv4, external-ip

I was wondering if there is a way to use the RIPE IPv4 address block owned by us on google cloud? We want the main external IP from the cloud computing to be ours and not one given by Google.

Thanks for the answers in advance
Regards
D.

Comment: What are you trying to do with those IP addresses? Are you trying to use them instead of RFC 1918 addresses for internal IPs? Or are you trying to use them as external IP addresses?

Comment: I've never heard of Google Cloud offering such a service. If you're a big enough customer, perhaps they can make some special arrangement. Contact Google enterprise support...

Comment: If there isn’t a way to configure that directly, you could also proxy requests through a machine that has the IP you want. Alternately, could you get away with pointing your domain at a different IP?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I need them as external IP addresses. The internal ones from google cloud are okay, but I want to use my own IP's instead of the given external ones from google...

Comment: I am sharing this google help [centre article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/custom-public-ip-addresses-on-compute-engine) which you might find helpful. This document shows how you bring your own external IP address to Google Cloud. This IP address has to be manually assigned to GCE VM and advertise back to the on-prem VPC from the Cloud Router with a Flexible Route Advertisement. It’s worth mentioning that this address will not be advertised publicly from Google’s edge network (AS 15169), but over the Cloud VPN connection.This would also apply over a Cloud Interconnect.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment whether it's possible on GCP but if you're open to other platforms AWS now supports exactly what you need since last week:

**[Bring Your Own IP for Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/announcing-the-general-availability-of-bring-your-own-ip-for-amazon-virtual-private-cloud/)**

Comment: The BYOIP is only supported in the US currently...

Comment: With AWS there is one huge issue, you can not assign IPs across regions. From their documentation: `You can bring each address range to one Region at a time.`.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud announced this feature as an Alpha release in October 2019. There is a [case study blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/bring-your-own-ip-addresses-the-secret-to-bitlys-shortened-cloud-migration) post and [some tutorial in the solutions section](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/custom-public-ip-addresses-on-compute-engine) that describes the implementation.

Also, note the important from the tutorial:

> This tutorial assumes that you have a provider-independent IP space
>   that you can advertise by using your own routing equipment.

If you value your time, I suggest wait, the implementation process looks unintuitive comparing to the competition and it will probably dramatically change in the future.